# Pass parameters from custom URL scheme to webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, url-scheme

I'm trying to pass parameters from an IOS custom url to a webview. So far I've implemented the webview in my main viewcontroller, and have implemented a delegate method to grab the params from the inbound URL.

For the second part I used the information provided here: [Launching your own application via a custom url scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Now. I can see the URL output in the console when I go to the app from safari. How do I then pass that information to the view and the webview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxm, from the app delegate function load your view controller (creating it or performing a segue if needed) and call a function that can pass the param to the web view and load it. something like:

```
- (void)refreshPageWithUrl:(NSString*)url{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
```